# Tweak Focus Visual Properties at app level in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to alter the focus visual properties at app level.(like the Mail App).
As per the [Focus Visual Docucmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/guidelines-for-visualfeedback#high-visibility-focus-visuals), it is possible to change the primary and secondary border color at app level by changing the respective system brush resources.

> There are only two color properties for the focus visuals: the primary
>    border color, and the secondary border color. These focus visual
>    border colors can be changed per-control on an page level, and
>    globally on an app-wide level:
>
> To brand focus visuals app-wide, override the system brushes:
>
> ```
>  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlFocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Color="DarkRed"/>
>  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlFocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Color="Pink"/>
> ```

But no such thing is provided in the doc for the thickness of the focus visual. Is there any resource available or any other way to specify the thickness at app level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no such resources for primary and secondary system focus visuals. But assuming you are using the default styles for your controls, you can try defining a *base* style and then have all the controls that you need a focus visual with inherit from it.

You can even define the colors and margin within the *base* style so this way you have one centralized place to manage all global focus styling.

```
<Style x:Name="DefaultFrameworkElementStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="DarkRed" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="Red" />
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="2" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultFrameworkElementStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultFrameworkElementStyle}" />
```

Comment: It seems this is the only way, pity for msft two years later.